# removefromsuperview and addsubview not changing display

Tags: ios

I'm pretty new to iOS development, and I'm trying to develop a simple app in which a button changes the subviews. I have a base `RootViewController`, which displays `MiddleView` correctly on `init`. `MiddleView` has a single button, labeled "First," which is connected (in Interface Builder) to `RootViewController`'s `-openFirstView`.

Here's how `MiddleView` is displayed within `RootViewController`'s `-viewDidLoad`

```
MiddleViewController *middleTemp = [[MiddleViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MiddleView" bundle:nil];
    self.middle = middleTemp;
    self.middle.rootViewController = self;
    [self.view addSubview:middle.view];
    [middleTemp release];
```

So I have the following `ViewControllers`s: `MiddleViewController` and `FirstController` which control `MiddleView` and `FirstView` respectively, and a `RootViewController` which switches between the two.

I've linked this by placing a `RootViewController` reference in `MiddleViewController`, and adding

```
self.middle.rootViewController = self;
```

to `RootViewController`'s `-viewDidLoad`.

```
-(IBAction)openFirstView:(id)sender{
    [middle.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view addSubview:firstController.view];
}
```

Note: I've tried initializing firstController within `-openFirstView`, and when it initially didn't run, I moved the initialization to `-viewDidLoad` and have proven that it is initializing from the nib correctly by displaying FirstView directly in `-viewDidLoad`

Where `firstController` is loaded to a reference earlier in code. However, when I run the code and click the button, nothing in the view changes.

I've done some more diagnosing. I've found specifically that `-ViewDidLoad` in `rootViewController` is being called twice, once on the original load and once on the first click of the button, and I'm not sure exactly why.

Comment: I'm confused. Can you please list the `UIViewController`s that you have and what `UIView`s they control? Also, please post the snippet for how you are displaying `MiddleView` within the `RootViewController`.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay, I've updated it now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you haven't inialize your firstView in the below method

```
-(IBAction)openFirstView:(id)sender{
    [middle.view removeFromSuperview];
    //First initialize the firstController
    [self.view addSubview:firstController.view];
}
```

Comment: I tried initializing `firstController` in `-openFirstView` originally, and then I moved the initialization to `-viewDidLoad` to see if there was a problem there. In any case, the lack of initialization isn't the problem. I'll add an edit to make that clear.